# How to turn off the anti-aliasing in WPF shapes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, drawing

I draw a rectangle using:

```
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="6"> </Rectangle>
```

but there is anti-aliasing applied to it. Is there a way to turn this off? I want it to be sharp and clear.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A little late but `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` does the trick

```
<Rectangle Width="300"
           Height="100"
           Stroke="Blue"
           StrokeThickness="6"
           RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
```

Comment: I have noticed significant performance degradation with this method. Perhaps it is driver bound but I have a suspicion that it falls back to software.

Answer (score 5):

Check out SnapToDevicePixels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx

Comment: This doesn't actually turn off the anti-aliasing. It allows you to force WPF to render graphics to match the device or display matrix, thus prevent blurrying in some cases. The effect is similar to Mac OS X vs. Windows font smoothing.

Answer (score 4):

Turning off anti-aliasing is not what you are looking for, seeing as you dont have a radius applied to the corners.

If you are using .Net 4 or above, turn on UseLayoutRounding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.95).aspx