# Image not displayed pixel to pixel

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I'm puzzled.

I have created a PNG image that to be a divider in my application display and the image is 3 pixels high like this:

[image]

However when I display it on my C# WPF window and run it, the divider is shown to be about 4 pixels instead, with the colours being off.

### Code:

```
<StackPanel Height="3">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/divider.png" Stretch="None"
            AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" Viewport="0,0,20,3" 
            ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="FlipX" />
    </StackPanel.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

### Output and Zoom:

[image]

What I've thought would be that the image is "stretched" (despite `Stretch="None"`) or there is some mechanism to optimize the image, so I did away with the image and wrote it with 3 rectangles with the same color and 1 pixel height each like this:

```
<StackPanel Height="3" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Rectangle Fill="#484848" Height="1" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#222" Height="1" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#484848" Height="1" />
</StackPanel>
```

However the results were similar: 4 pixels and colours run off (not exact colours as specified):

[image]

Other than pixels being off, the colours are off too. My colours are supposed to be `#484848`, `#222222`, `#484848`. When displayed on the WPF window, the shades goes off a little (too many shades of grey!)

I need the separator to fill the window with too as the window gets resized. I'm a perfectionist and I want that 3 pixel height separator to be pixel perfect. Any solution to solve that problem?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it may have something to do with WPF's anti-aliasing.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738956/disabling-antialiasing-on-a-wpf-image.  Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585082/how-to-turn-off-the-anti-aliasing-in-wpf-shapes.

Comment: Have you tried setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to true ? Edit : @BrianSnow was quicker than me !

Comment: Tried: Pixel count is correct but the colours are still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Brian and @Sisyphe, I am able to display the lines properly. However this is still a solution done through `Rectangle` displays and I reckon there's a better solution.

Here's my current solution:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="3">
    <Rectangle Fill="#484848" Height="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#222222" Height="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#484848" Height="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
</StackPanel>
```